# For Loop Will Print Multiples but not Append to List

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to create two lists of multiples of two integers. The for loop will print the multiples but it will not append these multiples to their respective lists. How can I append the multiples to the lists?

```
integer1 = int(input('input integer1: '))
integer2 = int(input('input integer2: '))

multiple_list1 = []
multiple_list2 = []

def multiples(n, list):
    list = []
    for i in range(n*100):
        if i % n == 0:
            #print(i)
            list.append(i)

print(multiples(integer1, multiple_list1))
print(multiples(integer2, multiple_list2))
```

Comment: @Vicrobot: they are not using keywords as identifiers. `list` is not a keyword. It's not a good idea to use the name `list` as a variable, but that doesn't make it a keyword. :-)

Comment: You are ignoring the list passed into `multiples`, instead *replacing* it in the local `list` variable with `list = []`. Remove that line.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Among other things, look at (`print`) the values at strategic places in your program.  You've made at least two fatal errors in moving values between the main program and the function, and then tried to run the whole program without testing the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reassign `list` inside the function. Now the variable no longer refers to the caller's list.

If you want to empty the list first, assign to a slice.

```
def multiples(n, list):
    list[:] = []
    for i in range(n*100):
        if i % n == 0:
            #print(i)
            list.append(i)
```

It's also not a good idea to use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in class name.

BTW, a better way to get all the multiples of `n` is:

```
list[:] = range(0, n*100, n)
```